# Incluir registros sin cumplir la condición

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT DISTINCT SQnet_Locations.DESCR, SQnet_TestDefinitions.CHECK_STATUS FROM (((SQnet_TestValues INNER JOIN SQnet_TestDefinitions ON SQnet_TestValues.MEASURE_DT = SQnet_TestDefinitions.LAST_CHECK) INNER JOIN SQnet_Users ON SQnet_TestValues.USR_CODE = SQnet_Users.REC_CODE) INNER JOIN SQnet_Locations ON SQnet_TestDefinitions.PARENT_CODE = SQnet_Locations.REC_CODE) INNER JOIN SQnet_Measures ON SQnet_TestValues.MEASURE_ID = SQnet_Measures.REC_CODE WHERE convert(date,SQnet_TestDefinitions.LAST_CHECK) >= convert(date,getdate()-1) AND SQnet_Locations.DESCR like '%VWCUV%' ORDER BY  SQnet_Locations.DESCR ASC
```

Necesito que saque los datos que cumplen la condición de la fecha y que los registros que no lo cumplen aparezcan con un "0", pero respetando el **ORDER BY**

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: tu consulta usa `distinct` y devuelve 2 campos. Creo que la pregunta está incompleta, a menos que quieras que ambos campos retornen `0`, en cuyo caso el `distinct` haría que todos los registros que no cumplen se reflejen en uno solo. Tomate el tiempo para explicar bien qué es lo que buscas y, mejor aún, si incluyes un pequeño ejemplo de l resultado que buscas.

Comment: Hola Patricio, gracias por la respuesta. En mi tabla SQL se hacen unas mediciones a unos tornillos y cuando se importa la medición los datos se machacan, quedando el registro mas reciente de cada tornillo. Si la medición es OK SQnet_TestDefinitions.CHECK_STATUS da 3 y si es NOK da 2. Si uso mi consulta con el distinct solo aparecen los tornillos que cumplen la condición de fechas de mi where. SI pongo ALL aparecen todos, pero en los que no se han medido bajo esa condicion les aparece (2 o 3) según el resultado de su última medición. Necesitaria que esos tornillos que no se han medido

Comment: aparezcan con un 1 en esa consulta y en ese campo

Answer (score 3):

En primer lugar agrega la columna nueva al `SELECT`, con el `CASE` en función si se cumple o no la condición de fecha, retornamos 1 o 0:

```
CASE WHEN convert(date,SQnet_TestDefinitions.LAST_CHECK) >= convert(date,getdate()-1) 
          THEN 1 
          ELSE 0 
END
```

Y obviamente debes eliminar esta condición del `WHERE`.